# Powershell csv delete row

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to delete rows from csv base off certain conditions in two columns. Status column if it has T and the second column is Term Date if the date is older then the past 5 days.

little info column STATUS has either "A" or "T".

```
$path = "data.csv"
$maxAge = (Get-Date).AddDays(-5).Date
Import-Csv $path | Where-Object {$_.STATUS -eq "A" -or $_.TERMDATE -gt $maxAge} | 
Export-Csv -Path temp.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

it works to a certain degree, but still shows dates from last year.

Comment: Use `[datetime]$_.TERMDATE -gt $maxAge` in your condition. `$_.TERMDATE` is going to be a string when read from CSV. It is likely not accurate for your comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to cast the `TERMDATE` value to a `datetime` object in order to make an accurate comparison.

```
$path = "data.csv"
$maxAge = (Get-Date).AddDays(-5).Date
Import-Csv $path |
    Where-Object {$_.STATUS -eq "A" -or [datetime]$_.TERMDATE -gt $maxAge} |
        Export-Csv -Path temp.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If the `[datetime]` cast does not work, then you will need to parse the string and perform a conversion. In order to provide a solution for that, we need to know the original date format of `TERMDATE`.

Comment: worked thank you. how would i go about counting work days only.